# convert http get to post in angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs, post, get

I am converting an already existing http.get request to a http.post request due to security reasons.
even though the code i have written is working, i dont think it is very robust. Is there a better way to define the data object?

I would prefer sending a dictionary and reading it in the back end.

Sample code goes as below.

```
http.get("/ajax/validate_login.py",{params:{"email":$scope.userEmail,"password":$scope.password}}).then(function(response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```

is converted to

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/ajax/validate_login.py?',
          data: 'email=' + $scope.userEmail + '&password=' + $scope.password ,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

is there a better way to define data in post request ?

Back end code is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import json
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
import sys



form = cgi.FieldStorage()

email=form["email"].value
password = form["password"].value


print "Content-Type: application/json"
print
```

Comment: use $resource instead of $http, there is good way you can make factory to use services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [$httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) to transform your object into a string which is added to the payload. There is a particular one that acts like jQuery's which I believe is what you are looking for.

Example:

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

More information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike